# AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user' in flask using g

Tags: python, flask

i have many .py file in insidemyapp

```
@def_app.before_request
def before_request():
    if 'user' in session:
        if session['type']=='rest':
            try:
                r=query_db('select email,name,r_area,city,mobile_no,r_image,r_id from rest_user where email =%s',[session['user']])
                if r:
                    for i in r:
                        g.user=i
                        break
            except:
                pass
        else:
            try:
                r= query_db('select email,name,street,city,mobile_no,image from r_users where email = %s',[session['user']])
                if r:
                    for i in r:
                        g.user=i
                        print(g.user)
                        break
            except:
                pass
```

**when i use g.user in other py file we get an error (AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user')**

this happen when i convert my single app file into multiple using blueprint

**error result**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\mehrab alam\Google Drive\organized\myapp\insidemyapp\profile.py", line 25, in profile
    print(g.user)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'
```

please help..............

Comment: There are many paths that don't set the `user` attribute. For example, if the first `if` is false the rest of the function is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways that you can address keeping the context and sharing `before_request` between Flask applications that use blueprints.

Why you're getting an error:

`my_blueprint.before_request` gets called before each request within [`my_blueprint` only.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_request)

If your other file is not in that blueprint, you need to do some more work.

Here are some options:

1. If you need something to run before *all* requests in *all* blueprints, use `before_app_request`.
   http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_app_request
2. If you have a before_request command that you want to re-use (but not set globally), write your `before_request` function, store it in a file, import it, and feed it to the decorator.

e.g. `utils/shared_functions.py`:

```
from flask import g, session

from app.users.models import Users

def before_request():
    """pull user info from the database based on session id"""

    g.user = None

    if 'user_id' in session:
        try:
            try:
                g.user = Users.query.get(session['user_id'])
            except TypeError:  # session probably expired
                pass
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

and then in your calling file `site_view.py`:

```
from ..utils import shared_functions

my_module = Blueprint('reviews', __name__, url_prefix='/cat_farm')
my_module.before_request(shared_functions.before_request)
```

the second way will allow you to discriminately apply the `before_request` function to blueprints without storing it in every file.